# Basic SigmaJS edgeLabel example does not work (does not show labels) with build

Tags: sigma.js

I am trying to use the edgeLabel plugin https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.renderers.edgeLabels

Here's my file:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="sigma.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.parsers.json.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/settings.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.curve.js"></script>
<script src="sigma.renderers.edgeLabels/sigma.canvas.edges.labels.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script>
  s = sigma.parsers.json('data.json', {
    container: 'container',
    renderer: {
      type: 'canvas'
    },
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#D3D3D3',
      defaultEdgeColor: '#D3D3D3',
      edgeLabelThreshold: 0,
      edgeLabelSize: 'proportional'
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the data I'm using:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "n0",
      "label": "Data1",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "size": 10
    },
    {
      "id": "n1",
      "label": "Data2",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 2, 
      "size": 10
    },
    {
      "id": "n2",
      "label": "Merged data",
      "x": 2,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 10
    },
    {
      "id": "n3",
      "label": "Cleaned data",
      "x": 3,
      "y": 1,
      "size": 10
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "label": "merge",
      "source": "n0",
      "target": "n2",
      "line": "arrow",
      "size": 20
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "label": "merge",
      "source": "n1",
      "target": "n2",
      "line": "arrow",
      "size": 20
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "label": "cleanAsync",
      "source": "n2",
      "target": "n3",
      "line": "arrow",
      "size": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried running this data in the example file given [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/edge-renderers.html)

And it works!

However, when I try this with my own, very similar file, it does not work.

The only difference I see here is that the example file imports everything on its own rather than using the built up file. However, the README states that you should only have to import the 4 files given in the folder, so I am stumped.

I am not particularly eager to go through each of the many imported files to see which one contains the thing edgeLabels is missing. No errors are thrown in console.

Comment: I don't know what the problem you are having is, but here's a working example similar to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/nc7jtnct/

Comment: Woops. The issue is that the edges don't have labels, only the nodes. Mine looks identical to your fiddle